# Tietze's extension theorem for contractible manifolds

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, manifolds

I've read that the Tietze's extension theorem was still valid for continuous applications from a closed subspace of a normal topological space to a contractible topological manifold.

But I can't find any clear reference for this result.

What I have found is that the theorem generalize to applications from a normal space to an Absolute Retract (but for which family ? Normal spaces ? Metric spaces ? both ?), that manifolds are ANR (Abolute Neighbourhood Retract, once again for which family of spaces ?), and that Contractible ANR implies AR. Is this correct ?

Is there a direct proof somewhere that Tietze generalizes to contractible manifolds ?

Comment: If you’ll not receive an answer here at MSE, I recommend you to ask your question at MathOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that a contractible ANR is an AR (it's iff even). And an AR is an absolute extensor (i.e. we can extend Tietze with images in that space).

All this is classical (I learnt it from "Infinite-dimensional topology, prerequisites and an introduction", Jan van Mill" (no longer in print, I believe);in that book all spaces are separable metric. I seem to recall a book by Hu, on absolute retracts, which covers the theory for normal spaces, IIRC. Maybe Dugundji's book Topology ? (it's the kind of thing I'd expect to find there).

Comment: does manifolds are AR (or AE) for both classes of normal and metrizable spaces ? But maybe it doesn't matter since I ma interested in extension of a map between manifolds, which are both normal and metrizable ?

Comment: @ychemama not always. It will need to be contractible. So spheres are out.

Comment: yes, but what about my question regarding the classes of spaces ? (BTW I do like your demo the Shrinking Lemma, it's clear and neat...)

Comment: I think metrisable manifold AR's will be AE(Normal), no reference beyond what i suggested